# How to pass the selected filename from tkfiledialog GUI to another function

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, backend

I'm building a simple desktop application using Tkinter that has a browse button for the user to be able to select file from their computer (below code is in a file called gui.py):

```
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox


class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()

        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")

        button_browse = Tkinter.Button(self, text = u"Browse", command = lambda:self.entryVariable.set(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()))


        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Go",
                                 command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button_browse.grid(column=1,row=0)
        button.grid(column=2,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                              anchor="w",fg="black",bg="white")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=3,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Hello !")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)


    def OnButtonClick(self):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You clicked the button)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You pressed ENTER)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Now, when the user clicks on the button "Go", I want the selected filename to be passed to the following function (which is outside the class), in place of the `"filename"` variable and the output of this program should be returned in the gui in the "`labelvariable`":

```
def main():
    data=[]
    total_top5=[]
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
    sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
        text = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=1)   
        data.append(text)

    #data = unicode(x).encode('UTF8') for x in data
    new_data=[]
    for x in data:    
        new_data.append(unicode(x[0]).encode('UTF8'))
```

I have never worked with Tkinter or creating GUI in python before, so any kind of help will be appreciated please.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "passed to"? Do you mean the gui app would import the file and run a function inside it, or predict.py instantiating simpleapp_tk and making it set a variable?

Comment: @Uzzee So, I added how the GUI looks above. When a person clicks on the Browse button and selects a file, I want that filepath to go into the "filename" variable in the "main" function above. Forget they being in different files. I made them in the same file now.

Comment: Okay, I posted an answer on this covering several scenarios, just give me a comment if you have any questions!

Comment: Start by not using lambda. It's much easier to debug proper functions.

Answer (score 0):

#### What i think you meant

This is a solution for what I assume that you mean when you say that you want the name of the selected file passed to predict.py

Inside predict.py, make these changes;

First import the GUI

```
from gui import simpleapp_tk
```

Second, make the main function be passed an argument

```
def main(filename="test.foo"):
```

Lastly, in your run routine, instantiate the GUI, get the filename, and run the main function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
    # Here it will wait until the GUI finishes and exits
    filename = app.labelVariable.get()
    main(filename)
```

#### What also can be done

You could from the gui.py import predict.py and change the method call of the "Go" button.

or,

If you make button_browse an attribute of simpleapp_tk, you could easily  set the command of it externally if you would import the GUI elsewhere, this is inside predict.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.configure(command=main(tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()))
    app.mainloop()
```