# Python 3 Tkinter - How to call a function from another class

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get my save button to call a function from another class. I would like to click on the save button as much as I want and it should print "hello people" every time. Though, I am having trouble in getting the save button to work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


class Application(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack() 
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        #save button
        self.saveLabel = tk.Label(self.parent, text="Save File", padx=10, pady=10)
        self.saveLabel.pack()
        #When I click the button save, I would like it to call the test function in the documentMaker class
        self.saveButton = tk.Button(self.parent, text = "Save", command = documentMaker.test(self))
        self.saveButton.pack()


class documentMaker():
    def test(self):

      print ("hello people")  

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root) 
app.master.title('Sample application')
object = documentMaker()
object.test()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: See this question I answered a while back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012740/how-to-pass-the-selected-filename-from-tkfiledialog-gui-to-another-function

Comment: Try to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+call+a+function+from+another+class&oq=how+to+call+a+function+from+a&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.10235j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=python+how+to+call+a+function+from+another+class) your title. There many results that answer just this question. This kind of question is very easy to find an answer on google and stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call Class Method From Another Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856413/call-class-method-from-another-class)

Answer (score 2):

In your `documentMaker` class, change the `test` method to a `@staticmethod`:

```
class documentMaker():
    @staticmethod
    def test(cls):   
      print ("hello people")
```

Then your `saveButton`'s command can be:

```
command = documentMaker.test
```

A `staticmethod` is bound to the class, not to an instance of the class like an instance method. So, we can call it from the class's name directly.  If you did not want it to be a `staticmethod`, you could keep it an instance method and have the command line change to:

```
command = documentMaker().test
```