# Tkinter - Using a Button command in a class to call a function from another class

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

My program is using a button from class First to trigger the function in class Second. However, when the button was press, it requires me to include a self argument, so how can I call the other function by using static method suggested form here ([Python 3 Tkinter - How to call a function from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478645/python-3-tkinter-how-to-call-a-function-from-another-class)) or using other alternative way to solve this.

If you can suggest me on how to use that StringVar in class Second,it will be more easy for me, Regards.

**The only part of the code that I think should modify:**

```
self.traceButton=Button(self.main_inner_frame,text="Trace",command=Second.printSecondLine())
```

The Second class code:

```
class Second(First):
    # @staticmethod
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)

    def printSecondLine(self):
        content = self.traceEntry.get()
        print(content)
```

If you need a Full Code:

```
from tkinter import *
class First(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__()
        master.minsize(width=755, height=520)
        master.maxsize(width=755, height=520)
        Grid.config(self)

        # Run all function in [First Class]
        self.widget_size()
        #self.getTEXT()

    def widget_size(self):

        # Define a small frame for it
        self.main_inner_frame = LabelFrame(self,text="Tracing Method",height= 120,width =355)
        self.main_inner_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0)
        self.main_inner_frame.grid_propagate(0)

        # Create a button for it [When trace click it will show the text in the entry on terminal]
        self.traceButton = Button(self.main_inner_frame, text="Trace",command=Second.printSecondLine())
        self.traceButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

        # Create a entry box for the user
        # use a string variable tvar
        tvar = StringVar()
        self.traceEntry = Entry(self.main_inner_frame,textvariable=tvar,width=30)
        self.traceEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

    # def getTEXT(self):
        # content = self.traceEntry.get()
        # print(content)

class Second(First):
    # @staticmethod
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)

    def printSecondLine(self):
        content = self.traceEntry.get()
        print(content)
        return content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Good System")
    TIF = First(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Expected Result** 
When user press button,the entry will get the text and show in terminal.

Comment: Move `printSecondLine()` to `First` and get rid of the pointless `Second`. Then `command=self.printSecondLine`

Comment: For this function confirm is pointless. But I have a huge class which confirm will store in another file, if I solve this minimize program, I can do the following  things in my big program:
In Second class, I will use to trace all the windows user activity history, therefore, this part I will just use to get XXX text from a file dialog directory, which i already know the way to do that,just need to get from another class than should be no problem for me. If is pointless, I would not create this to help me solve bigger problem in my program...hope you understand.thank you

Comment: If I follow your recommendation, for simple program is ok. But my First program is already a main interface for gathering evidence, so there is no point for me put a complicated code inside a file which is already have so much code in it, I do that only for clean code purpose.

Comment: You can have a `Second` class and yet have `printSecondLine` in `First` (and give everything better, meaningful names, by the way). It is not clear why `printSecondLine` should be in `Second` if everything it does is related to `First`.

Comment: This is my full system code: wuahts3 is my main python.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mk9Y39oCYWvrtBxd4_dxiBsfd5RTyWID

For the huge example : all the tracing process for windows evidence will do in another Class, inside have one function need to open file dialog directory when user press trace button in main file( wuahts3), in future will be one button for more than one function from diffrent class

So can you help me if I need just to need get that funtion from second class to achive my goal? (base on my small example, I am sure there is a way right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved.** I did a few things to get your code to work according your desired specifications:

1. added @staticmethod above the printSecondLine() method.
2. removed self from  the printSecondLine() parameter list.
3. made printSecondLine() accept a parameter named value.
4. gutted and re-wrote the body of the printSecondLine() method so that it functions as intended.
5. used a lambda expression in the Button configuration, so that data can be passed easily.
6. put tvar as the lambda expression's parameter, since that is what you are tying to pass to printSecondLine()
7. put the tvar and Entry code above the Button code. it might be fine in the other order. but i think it is better to put tvar above, since you then declare it before you access it from Button.

Anyway, it works.  You enter data into entry, click the button, and the data goes the console.  You will probably want to write code that clears the Entry field once the button is clicked. But that is a different topic and not difficult to do.

```
from tkinter import *

class First(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__()
        master.minsize(width=755, height=520)
        master.maxsize(width=755, height=520)
        Grid.config(self)

        # Run all function in [First Class]
        self.widget_size()


    def widget_size(self):

        # Define a small frame for it
        self.main_inner_frame = LabelFrame(self,text="Tracing Method",height= 120,width =355)
        self.main_inner_frame.grid(row= 0, column=0)
        self.main_inner_frame.grid_propagate(0)

        # Create a entry box for the user
        # use a string variable tvar
        tvar = StringVar()
        self.traceEntry = Entry(self.main_inner_frame,textvariable=tvar,width=30)
        self.traceEntry.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = W)

        # Create a button for it [When trace click it will show the text in the entry on terminal]
        self.traceButton = Button(self.main_inner_frame, text="Trace",command=lambda: Second.printSecondLine(tvar))
        self.traceButton.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)


class Second(First):
    @staticmethod
    def __init__(self,master):
        super().__init__(master)

    @staticmethod
    def printSecondLine(value):
        print(value.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Good System")
    TIF = First(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> when creating buttons you cannot set command= to function with parantheses '()' unless using lambda like this.

```
self.traceButton = Button(self.main_inner_frame,text="Trace",
command= lambda: Second.printSecondLine())
```

But this should work as well:

```
 self.traceButton = Button(self.main_inner_frame, text="Trace",command=Second.printSecondLine)
```

Comment: Yap, using command=Second.printSecondLine, it shows Type Error: missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'